# How to create water waves with Ogre3d WaterMesh class?

Tags: mesh, ogre3d

I would like to use the water and waterMesh classes from the Ogre3D Demos in order to create the water with some waves. For the moment I added the classes in my project and create a waterMesh Object in this way:

```
    WaterMesh *waterMesh;
    waterMesh = new WaterMesh("waterMesh", 100.0f, 64);
```

Great, I have a water surface 100×100. I would like to create some waves now. I can I do it?Is it `updateMesh` that I should use?

Comment: Cross-post from Ogre3D forums: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=81099

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://gitorious.org/ogre3d/mainlinemirror/source/3456c55d9543dc571bdb9ae1879be71772aec511%3aSamples/Water/src/WaterMesh.cpp) I think that you can only `push` a surface at some point, and the WaterMesh will compute resulting waves after some delta time in its `updateMesh` method. There seems to be no way to create a typical 'ocean' waves, unless you modify the source code.

But if it's all you need, then use the `push(Real x, Real y, Real depth, bool absolute)` method.